# Update a div with name from type file upload

Tags: jquery, types

I'm trying to change the value of a div to the name of the file uploaded. In my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/u5w17dug/) you can see the browse works fine but the div isn't being updated. Would someone please explain how to do this?

```
    <form action="#">
    <input type="file" name="up_image_0" id="fileupload_0" onChange="ShowImageName('0')">
    <input type="file" name="up_image_1" id="fileupload_1" onChange="ShowImageName('1')">

    <input type="text" name="color_image_0" value="" id="img-holder_0">
    <input type="text" name="color_image_1" value="" id="img-holder_1">
    </form>

    <script>
     function ShowImageName(idx) {
      var new_name = $("#fileupload_"+idx).val();
      $("#img-holder_"+idx).text(new_name);
     } 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/u5w17dug/2/

```js
ShowImageName = function(idx) {
  $("#img-holder_"+idx).val($("#fileupload_"+idx).val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input type="file" name="up_image_0" id="fileupload_0" onChange="ShowImageName('0')">
  <input type="file" name="up_image_1" id="fileupload_1" onChange="ShowImageName('1')">

  <input type="text" name="color_image_0" value="" id="img-holder_0">
  <input type="text" name="color_image_1" value="" id="img-holder_1">
</form>
```

Change the code `$("#img-holder_"+idx).text(new_name);` to `$("#img-holder_"+idx).val(new_name);`

For assigning value to an `input` using `jQuery` use `.val()` method not `.text()`.

Comment: this answer is true in a way. actually his problem is a little different. In the fiddle, `ShowImageName` is not found, probably because declared after (jsfiddle oddity?) it works in yours because of var hoisting i guess (you changed the function declaration)